# $ N $ be a minimal normal and $ K $ is a $ p $-nilpotent normal subgroup, then $ [ N , K ] = 1 $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ G $ is a finite group and $ N $ be a minimal normal subgroup of $ G $ whose order is divisible by $ p $, that $ p $ is a prime. Prove that if $ K $ is normal $ p $-nilpotent subgroup of $ G $, then $ [ N , K ] =1 $. 
For proof i think, since $ N \lhd G $ and $ K \lhd G $, then $ [N , K] \lhd G $ and $ [N , K] \leq N $. Since $ N $ is a minimal normal, hence $ [N , K] = 1 $ or $ [N , K] = N $. Let $ [ N , K ] = N $, then how prove $ [N , K] = 1 $ ?

Comment: Then you have $N=[N,K]\leq K$ and $K$ is nilpotent. What do minimal normal subgroups of nilpotent groups look like?

Comment: @DavidHill A minimal normal subgroup must be a cyclic group of prime order contained in the center.

Comment: So $N\leq Z(K)$. What does that tell you about $[N,K]$?

Comment: But $N$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G$, and we are not told that $G$ is nilpotent. In fact you have not said what $p$ is. Is $N$ assumed to be a $p$-group?

Comment: $ N $ is a minimal normal subgroup of $ G $ whose order is divisible by $ p $, that $ p $ is a prime.

Comment: @DavidHill $ [N , K ] \leq 1 $ ?

Comment: That was the reasoning I was going for, but Derek points out that $N$ may not be a minimal normal subgroup of $K$. It still follows that $[N,K]$ is a proper subgroup of $N$ (Let $i$ be maximal such that $N\leq K^{(i)}$, where $K^{(0)}=K$ and $K^{(i)}=[K^{(i-1)},K]$. Then $[N,K]\leq K^{(i+1)}\cap N\lneq N$.)

Comment: If let $ [ N , K ] \neq 1 $, since $ [N,K] \leq N \cap K $, then $ N \cap K \neq 1 $ and so $ N \leq K $. Since $ \vert N \vert $ divisible by $ p $, hence $ N \nleq O_{p^{\prime}}(K) $, so $ N \cap O_{p^{\prime}}(K) = 1 $ and hence $ N $ is a $ p $-group. Now how show $ [N , K] < N $ ?

Comment: Let $N \le Q \in {\rm Syl}_p(K)$. Then $N \unlhd Q$, so $[N,Q] < N$. But $K=O_{p'}(K)Q$ and $[N,O_{p'}(K)]=1$, so $[N,K] = [N,Q] < N$.

Comment: I explained why $[N,K] < N$ in my last comment.